# angular- localization- change language dynamically

Tags: javascript, angularjs

How to change the locale of a site using angular localization?

I need to change the date, currency and numbers depending on the language selected in the drop down. How can we load the file dynamically and set the language in angular controller, so that the dates, currency and numbers are updated dynamically depending on language selected?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular localization is not able to do this.
Use tmhDynamicLocale wich is a good way to do it easily
https://github.com/lgalfaso/angular-dynamic-locale